# SignedXml CanonicalizationMethod - http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11

Tags: c#, digital-signature, signedxml

Is it possible to use http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11 CanonicalizationMethod with SignedXml?

```
SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11";
```

is throwing

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Could not create the XML tr
ansformation identified by the URI http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11.
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like it has been implemented by .NET yet.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedinfo.canonicalizationmethod(v=vs.110).aspx

You may have to make your own Transform class like this:

```
public class XmlDsigC14N11Transform: XmlDsigC14NTransform
    {
        public override void LoadInput(object obj)
        {
            //do something here
            base.LoadInput(obj);
        }

        public override object GetOutput()
        {
            //do something here
            return base.GetOutput();
        }
    }
```

And map your transform to "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11".

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(XmlDsigC14N11Transform), "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11");
```

Comment: There is no need to override the `XmlDsigC14NTransform` as the https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n11/ are identical.  You can simply do ```CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(XmlDsigC14NTransform), "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11");```